# calculating link utilization using ns2

Tags: ns2, network-utilization

hi all
i want to calculate utilization of link between 2 node n0 and n1 in ns2 . i have out.tr file that contains trace-queue output for that link. please help me on this topic as soon as possible
thanks

Answer (score 1):

hi all
this very  simple question . you should collect sum of bytes received in end node (n1) and divide it by simulation time . then divide this number with link capacity.
thanks